# Question about well-ordering.

Tags: set-theory

I was wondering if the following statement is true working in $ZF$.

Let $\langle A_n: n<\omega\rangle$ be a family of sets such that $A_i\subseteq A_j$ whenever $i\leq j$. Suppose that each $A_i$ is well-orderable. Is it true that $\bigcup_{n \in \omega} A_n$ is well orderable?

For me, it looks like it's false (independent), but I really don't know.

Comment: There's a short proof of what I think is the identical statement, as Proposition 7 here: http://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/ii/Logic_and_Set_Theory.pdf The sets $A_i$ need not be nested, in fact.

Comment: Proposition 7 supposes that every $X_i$ has a fixed well order. We would need to fix an well order for each $A_i$ to use proposition 7.

Comment: Right, thanks for clarifying. (I'll leave the incorrect comment for anyone else who might have read the question as sloppily as I did!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. In $\mathsf{ZF}$, we cannot prove that a countable union of sets of size $2$ is well-orderable. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/249340/462) is an answer to a similar question (on a countable union of countable sets), with references.