# Prove that any countable cartesian product of countable sets is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I want to prove that infinite (yet countable) cartesian product of countable sets is countable.

Here's what I tried:

Step 1:

I proved that for 2 countable sets $ A_1,A_2 $ , the product $ A_{1}\times A_{2} $ is countable.

Step 2:

I proved by induction that for any $n\in \mathbb{N} $  if $ A_{1},...,A_{n} $ are countable sets, then

$ A_{1}\times A_{2}\times,...,\times A_{n} $  is countable.

Now, I want to show that any countable infinite cartesian product would be countable.

How do i show that  $ A_{1}\times,....\times A_{\aleph_{0}} $  is countable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general it's not countable... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500849/infinite-cartesian-product-of-countable-sets-is-uncountable

Comment: Isn't true.  $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$ isn't countable and if you consider a decimal expansion of a real number as an infinite-tuple of the digits $0$ to $9$ it's clear it is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you know that $[0,1)$ is uncountable. If your statement was true, then $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ would be countable. But there is a surjection of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ in $[0,1)$ since every $x\in[0,1)$ can be represented by a countable string of digits (writing it's decimal part in base 10 for instance). Then $[0,1)$ would be countable, which is absurd. So a countable cartesian product in general is not countable.

Comment: I see. so its true only for a finite cartesian product of countable sets. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that should answer your question:

[Infinite Cartesian product of countable sets is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500849/infinite-cartesian-product-of-countable-sets-is-uncountable)

[Countable collection of countable sets and Axiom of choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039725/countable-collection-of-countable-sets-and-axiom-of-choice)

Comment: When your answer is "This is impossible, see this answer for details", maybe the right approach is to post a comment and maybe vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: You are right but I really had no idea how to do that

Comment: Leaving a comment is easy. To vote to close you, as a user with less than 3k points, need to flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Alright, that ought to be useful in the future, thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can't prove it because it's false.

The countable product of two element sets is (essentially) the uncountable real unit interval when you think of elements of the product set as binary expansions.

[Infinite Cartesian product of countable sets is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500849/infinite-cartesian-product-of-countable-sets-is-uncountable)

Comment: When your answer is "This is impossible, see this answer for details", maybe the right approach is to post a comment and maybe vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Perhaps. The second paragraph outlines a quick counterexample, so I decided to post it. The nice accepted answer says essentially the same thing. The question could still be closed as duplicate.